# Is it possible to construct (without choice, even?) a non-finitely-generated group with no proper non-finitely-generated subgroup?

Tags: gr.group-theory, set-theory

Is there a non-finitely-generated group each of whose proper subgroups is finitely generated? If so, what form of choice (if any) is required to construct such a group?

Comment: The Prufer p-group. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(CW since this is just expanding on George Lowther’s comment to the question, which could really have been an answer in the first place; if George L wants to convert his answer to a comment himself, I can delete this one.)

For any prime $p$, the Prüfer $p$-group is as desired.

There are several constructions of this; a good one for present purposes is
$$\mathbb{Z}[1/p]\ /\ \mathbb{Z}$$
i.e. rationals with denominator a power of $p$, modulo the integers.

To see that this works, note that it is the union of the linearly ordered chain of finitely generated (indeed, cyclic) subgroups $H_i := \{ [a / p^i]\ |\ 0 \leq a < p^i \}$, over $i \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now any element of $H_{i+1}$ not in $H_{i}$ must be of the form $[a/p^{i+1}]$ with $a$ coprime to $p$, and hence generates the whole of $H_{i+1}$.  So any subgroup is either equal to some $H_i$, or else contains them all and is the whole group.

On the other hand, the entire group is clearly not finitely generated since any finite set of elements is contained in some $H_i$.

Comment: Sweet... didn't know this one. I'm quite charmed. 

Comment: @Peter: Thanks. That's just what I would have said. No need to delete this answer, as 6 people have already bothered upvoting it.

Comment: Also, every proper subgroup is cyclic, and not just finitely generated.

Comment: Excellent example and explanation---thanks!

It's still not clear to me to what extent choice is necessary for this example, but I'll look through the argument more closely later. (I was expecting a less clear-cut construction, I suppose.)

Comment: This group is isomorphic to the group of p-th power roots of unity in the complex numbers (restrict the isomorphism of Q/Z with the roots of unity to the subgroup of elements with p-power order). This is a more concrete model for the group. That every subgroup of this group is cyclic is related to the fact that any finite subgroup of the nonzero elements of a field is a cyclic group: any proper subgroup is missing some root of unity of order, say, $p^n$ and therefore has no root of unity of order p^n or higher, which means it is a finite subgroup.

Comment: @Zach: choice is not necessary at all; nor indeed is replacement.  The whole construction goes through in just Zermelo set theory.  It barely even needs classical logic — if we restrict consideration from “subgroups” to “decidable subgroups” it works in eg Intuitionistic Set/Type Theory with Markov’s principle.  (Markov’s principle is needed to make the inference “either $S$ is contained in some $H_i$, or it contains all of them”.)

Comment: @KConrad: I’m interested that you find the roots-of-unity presentation more concrete — is this essentially because the $\mathbb{Z}[1/p]\ /\ \mathbb{Z}$ presentation involves explicit quotienting, or is it some other reason that I’m missing?  I like both presentations, but (perhaps because I work a lot in constructive mathematics and formalisation) the rational version feels more ‘concrete’ to me, I guess because it is type-theoretically simpler — elements are explicitly represented just by pairs of integers, and so on.

Comment: @Peter: You're quite right. I'm not a group theorist, so I'm still a bit surprised to see that a group with (what is to me) such an unlikely property is so concrete. (I admit I didn't even expect an explicit construction.)

Comment: @KConrad: I agree with Peter that the $\mathbb{Z}[1/p]/\mathbb{Z}$ construction is more concrete, but thank you for the alternative. Maybe thinking about this group from a different perspective will help me grasp its weirdness.

Comment: The p-th power roots of unity can be viewed as a (dense) subset -- even subgroup -- of the unit circle, thus providing a natural context where the group of interest lives. That's why I consider the realization of this group as the p-th power roots of unity to be more concrete. I also like this point of view because it gives you another way to understand why the finite subgroups of this group are cyclic, as I wrote in my previous comment.